# Can't leave Page while Ajax (async)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX call which needs up to 20 seconds to complete. I want the user to be able to leave the site while this call is loading and not finished.

However when the user clicks on a link or the back button the site is waiting for the call to finish before the user gets redirected to the previous site or the link the user clicked on

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/getSupportTickets&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&email=<?php echo $email; ?>',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json) {
    //do stuff here
  }
});
```

Comment: That call is not synchronous so should not block the UI. Have you set `async: false` in a `$.ajaxSetup()` call somewhere?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  sounds like he's hit the nail on the head, if you have trouble finding the ajaxSetup, you could also confirm if it's this by overriding by passing -> `async: true` as an option.   Also if you look in the console it might give you a warning, Chrome will warn you if using sync calls.

Comment: Sounds like your server is set for single-requests.

Answer (score 2):

An AJAX call is no different from a regular HTTP call (it just happens behind the scenes). As such the server is still executing this call (getSupportTickets).

It sounds like your web server is actually blocking (i.e. you don't have any threading support or the CPU is 100% busy) which is giving you this illusion of a blocking call

Answer (score 2):

In your ajax call, use `session_write_close();` once you got the data of the session you needed.

Only 1 php script can run with 1 php session at the same time, sessions are 'locked' to the current script. The scripts which use `session_start()` will be blocked on that instruction until the session is freed.

If you release the session by using `session_write_close();` then your ajax script will be able to continue, while the new requests will be able to access the session (which is what was blocking).

Comment: `session_write_close()` is a server end, and won't stop client side back button.  Or are you thinking if it's the page its going back to that's maybe blocking and waiting for PHP, that's certainly an option.

Comment: The problem comes from the backend, not the frontend. When he tries to access a new page, the request won't be treated on the backend until the ajax call is finished, because it still hasn't released the PHP session. Got this problem a while ago, it's a classic PHP problem when you write a chat or notification system.

Comment: I think you have missed my point, it doesn't matter how long a PHP request takes it won't stop the browser back button been pressed or links been clicked.  But what it will do is block your next PHP page, and this is were I was agreeing with you.   IOW: The OP might think the back button has been prevented, but instead it's the render of the next page he's seeing.

Comment: Looks like you're both saying the same thing but adding "won't stop client back button" is just confusing the issue.  Client can close/redirect/whatever but it wont serve a new page until the ajax call is finished - and this is OPs issue.  There's no attempt to block the back/navigate and in fact OP wants to be able to navigate.

Comment: Question: if you call `session_write_close()`, will that effectively return the ajax call immediately?

Comment: No the session will be released, other process can now lock it, and the ajax call will continue normally. You just won't be able to edit the session variable in the ajax call

Comment: @freedomn-m  `"won't stop client back button" is just confusing the issue.`  I'm not sure it is, because that is the whole point!!, and the distinction is important.  A `sync` ajax request, will block/hang the browser UI (good reason why it's getting removed from main thread), on the other hand a long running server request never will.  If `session_write_close()` is the problem, it won't be because the UI back button or links have been prevented, but the next page request is waiting.  Yes, I am agreeing with Piere, but was just clarifying it's context and maybe it's what the OP is seeing.